# How to use strtok with unicode delimiters?

Tags: php

Looks like `strtok()` has problems with unicode delimiters like `،`- which is Farsi version of comma character `,` and others alike. Below is example working fine:

```
function tokenize($str) {
    $delimiters = ",.:;/\\()[]-_ \t\n\r";
    $tokens = [];
    $token = strtok($str, $delimiters);
    while ($token !== false) {
        if ($token && !in_array($token, $stopwords)) {
            $tokens[] = $token;
        }
        $token = strtok($delimiters);
    }
    return $tokens;
}

print_r(tokenize("ج. : مصور، نقشه رنگه ؛ 28 س م."));

/***** OUTPUT IS ******/
Array
(
   [0] => ج
   [1] => مصور،
   [2] => نقشه
   [3] => رنگه
   [4] => ؛
   [5] => 28
   [6] => س
   [7] => م
)
```

After adding `؛` and `،` delimiters below is the output:

```
Array
(
   [0] => �
   [1] => م
   [2] => �و
   [3] => �
   [4] => نق
   [5] => �ه
   [6] => �نگه
   [7] => 28
   [8] => �
   [9] => م
)
```

Comment: Like most basic PHP string functions, this is probably not safe for multi-byte encodings. Suggest you use `preg_split` with the unicode modifier instead.

Comment: What is `$stopwords` ?

Comment: This may be of help http://www.anastis.gr/mb_strtok-a-php-implementation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 04FS suggests you to use `preg_split()` to achieve the same goal. I would also recommend to use that function in this case. See the following examples:

without `؛` and `،` characters:

```
$str = "ج. : مصور، نقشه رنگه ؛ 28 س م.";

$tokens = preg_split("@[,.:;-_\s/()\[\]\-_\t\n\r]+@mui", $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($tokens);

Array
(
    [0] => ج
    [1] => مصور،
    [2] => نقشه
    [3] => رنگه
    [4] => ؛
    [5] => 28
    [6] => س
    [7] => م
)
```

and with `؛` and `،` characters:

```
$tokens = preg_split("@[؛،,.:;-_\s/()\[\]\-_\t\n\r]+@mui", $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($tokens);

Array
(
    [0] => ج
    [1] => مصور
    [2] => نقشه
    [3] => رنگه
    [4] => 28
    [5] => س
    [6] => م
)
```